# how to reduce height of Tab Bar in flutter

Tags: flutter, tabs, navigation

I am using Scaffold to show my bottom tab navigator, but it shows too high, is there a way to reduce size of height in my Tab Bar. here is the code

```
Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: Material(
        child: new TabBar(
          tabs: <Widget>[
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.home),text: 'Home'),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.settings),text: 'Settings')
          ],
          labelColor: Colors.blue,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: [
            MainScreen(),
            FirstPage(),
          ],
        ),

      )
```

Comment: Why don't you use `BottomNavigationBar` instead of `TabBar`... I believe `TabBar` is designed to go at the top of your screen

Comment: my data from api always re-render when I use ```BottomNavigationBar```, that's why I use Tab Bar to prevent that problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the `child: new TabBar()` in a container. And also change height of icon and text.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyButtomTabBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: Scaffold(
          bottomNavigationBar: Material(
            child: Container(
              height: 40,
              child: new TabBar(
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  Tab(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.home,
                      size: 15,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Home',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.settings,
                      size: 15,
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      'Settings',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
                labelColor: Colors.blue,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```